# In Select <Option> onCLick Event "Ajax function" Work In Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

In Option tag `onClick` Event work properly in Firefox and call myPurchaseTotal and Ajax work perfectly but In chrome its not work .
This is View File

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="product_id" name="product_id" style="" onchange="copy_data(this.form)">
    <option>Select Product</option>
    @foreach($product as $pro)                                  
        <option onclick="myPurchaseTotal('<?php echo $pro->p_id ?>', 'purchase_total')" value="{{$pro->p_id}}">{{$pro->p_name}}</option>
    @endforeach  
</select>
```

This Is Ajax Function

```
    function myPurchaseTotal(given_text, objID) {
    if (given_text) {
        serverPage = 'purchasetotal/' + given_text;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

        }

    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: saying `its not work` doesn't give us much to work with ... what errors do you see in the **developer** tools console

Comment: In Chrome onClick Event not Hit when I select option from dropdown list  So First I need to hit onClick event in chrome.

Comment: this is correct as your function defined
<option onclick="myPurchaseTotal( 'purchase_total','<?php echo $pro->p_id ?>')" value="{{$pro->p_id}}">{{$pro->p_name}}</option>

Comment: I think that should be better add an onchange event to the select input.

Comment: Yes its better. Can You give me jquery ajax function example and response text in ajax code ? I think this ajax code not suitable for this situation i need another type ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better use the onchange event from the select element for this kind of things and is also more cross browser compatible.

Here is a sample of how you can do it using your current functions. Just replace them and add the foreach for the select options.

https://jsbin.com/pagokavava/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="product_id" name="product_id" onchange="productIDOnChangeHandler(this)">
    <option value="pid_1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="pid_2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="pid_3">Product 3</option>
    <option value="pid_4">Product 4</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    function productIDOnChangeHandler(t) {
      copy_data(t.form);
      var select = document.getElementById('product_id');
      var index = select.selectedIndex;
      var given_text = select.options[index].value;
      myPurchaseTotal(given_text, 'purchase_total');
    }

    function copy_data(form) {
      // Your fn
      console.log(form);
    }

    function myPurchaseTotal(given_text, objId) {
      // Your fn
      console.log(given_text);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The null that you'll get on JSBin is because the select isn't in a form.

If you want to do it using jQuery or something for the ajax part, your script will be more cross browser compatible too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Problem Solved. I changed My Ajax Code and use Select Id.

```
$('#product_id').on('change', function() {               
            if ($("#product_id").val() != "") {                                
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/xcommerce/public/purchastotal/'+$(this).val(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (response){                      
                        $("#purchase_total").replaceWith(response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert("Something went wrong, please try again");
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```